# How do I get rid of java.lang.NoSuchMethod for lucene CompressionStoredFieldsFormat in trying Hibernate Search

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, lucene, hibernate-search

I am learning how to build Java enterprise application and a friend shared his project with me. Unfortunately, I'm not able to deploy to the project because i keep getting the error below:

```
09:53:58,540 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."asset-guard-1.0.war#assetGuardPU": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."asset-guard-1.0.war#assetGuardPU": java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.lucene.codecs.compressing.CompressingStoredFieldsFormat.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/lucene/codecs/compressing/CompressionMode;I)V
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:172)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:667)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
```

I tried including

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-codecs</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

in my POM but it still won't work.

Please help!

Comment: hey seems your ja in not compatible. as you are using jboss and jboss has  compatible jars for that version in client lib folder. kindly use only those jars or check on internet for compatible jars for your JEE version

Comment: @NaveenRamawat Thanks a lot. How do i know which jar will be compatible with the JEE version. Also is there a way i can disable the jars that jboss is providing and provide my own jars?

Comment: JBoss provided jars is most compatible and tested with that jboss and his EE version so it is not recommended  to disable those. jboss client jar will not be automatically added in path you have to put those selected required jars in your application.